# How can I set an underline in textarea with javaFX

Tags: javafx

I want to set an underline for my text area but I have a problem

I tried this with css but it doesn't work

```
.hyperlink-text-area .text {
-fx-underline: true ;
```

}

Comment: no screenshots of text .. just c&p, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create TextArea and add your style class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Test...");
        textArea.getStyleClass().add("text-area-underline-text");

        VBox vbox = new VBox(textArea);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 640, 480);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX App");
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Add your style in your application style.css file

```
.text-area-underline-text .text {
    -fx-underline: true ;
}
```

[image]